# Unable to create API for AWS Lambda fucntion which access S3 bucket

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm fairly new to AWS coding. So wrote a lambda function to access an S3 object Json file that is stored in my bucket. I get the output when I run the same from AWS CLI. But When I upload the function into lambda and try to creat an API. It doesn't workout for me. Following is my Lambda code and trust policy.

```
***************Lambda Handler************
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object('MyBucket','facebook.json')
x = object.get()["Body"].read()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    global x
    data = json.loads(x)
    name = data["data"][0]["from"]["name"]
    return str(name)


********TRUST RELATIONSHIP and POLICY********
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
     {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "s3:Get*",
          "s3:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
      }
   ]
}

***********EXECUTION OF LAMBDA FUNCTION************

Execution result: succeeded(logs)
The area below shows the result returned by your function execution.

"Tom Brady"

********ERROR WHILE CREATING API********
{"message": "Internal server error"}. I was also getting Security token error.

Thanks for your help.
Regards,
Tarun
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'error while creating api'? How are you creating it?

Comment: Hi Sorry for the delayed response. I am creating this in Lambda console. I code works from from AWS CLI/ lambda console.  But whenever I try to create an API trigger.

 It throws an error message " {"message": "Internal server error"}"

https://qvst2v4jta.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/fetch_obj

S3 Integration type as follows:

S3: jsonstorage
arn:aws:s3:::jsonstorage
Event type: ObjectCreatedByPutSuffix: .json

Comment: Can anyone help me with this problem ? :(